# HQL: playing with variables

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have these testing query:

```
String query = "";    
Query criteria;
query = 
  "from Test t " +
  "where (:value is null OR t.id = :value)"; // update: (t.id = (:value))

criteria = session.createQuery(query);

if (.. some condition ..) {
  criteria.setParameter("value", 0);
}
else {
  criteria.setParameter("value", null);
}
```

How to change the where condition from `id = 0` to `(id = 0 or id = 1)` (resp. `id < 2`) using `value` parameter only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "where in" operator. Then "value" will become collection parameter.

```
Query criteria;
query = 
  "from Test t " +
  "where (t.id in (:value))";

criteria = session.createQuery(query);
criteria.setParameterList("value", Arrays.asList(0, 1));
```

Comment: should be `criteria.setParameterList(Arrays.asList(0, 1));`

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't work. :( `unexpected AST node: {vector} [from tables.Test t where (:value0_, :value1_ is null OR t.id in (:value0_, :value1_))`

Comment: Try with `where t.id in (:value)`

Comment: May be problem is with :value0_, :value1_ is null expressions? Do you have :value is null in your query?

Comment: Do you really need :value is null there? You want to get all if value is null?

Comment: Yes, if the condition is not true, i need all the ids. If I change the hql to `....where (:value is null OR t.id in (0,1))`, it works fine. I can use that solution, but in the future, for more complicated "in" condition, it's not systematic :-)

Comment: You can have two queries, one with :value in condition, and other without any conditions or maybe findAll method?

Comment: I'll check it later, but it's solved for now. I think I am on the right way and you advised me "in" operator, so I accept your answer, thank you :-)

Comment: Thanks, please comment here if any other questions